# jQuery autocomplete issue - each character on separate line

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to get an autocomplete text box working. Here is the code that I have so far:

```
if ($action == 'find_products')
{
    $dept = $_POST['dept'];

    $stk_adddep = "
        SELECT * FROM stocktake_products WHERE stocktake_id = '{$stocktake_id}' AND is_deli = 0 AND department_description LIKE '{$dept}%' LIMIT 10; ";

     $result = db::c()->query($stk_adddep);
     while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   $data[] = array(
        'full_name' => $row['product_name'],
        'value' => $row['product_name']);
}
    echo json_encode($data);
    die();
}
```

Div to display the text box:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="customerAutocomplte" />
```

JS code:

```
$('#customerAutocomplte').autocomplete({

            source: function( request, response ) {
            var dept = $('#customerAutocomplte').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo Navigation::gUrl('/users/admin/stocktake_details_nonbcodeditems.php', array('stocktake_id' => $stocktake_id, 'action' => 'find_products'));?>',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'dept':dept},
                         success: function( data ) {
                         response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                            return {
                                label: item,
                                value: item
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                });
            },
            autoFocus: true,
            minLength: 0        
          });
```

PHP part seems to be working fine, the response that I get is as follows:

> [{"full_name":"Prince Hubert Cristal","value":"Prince Hubert Cristal"},{"full_name":"Schloer","value"
>   :"Schloer"},{"full_name":"Underberg 20ml","value":"Underberg 20ml"},{"full_name":"Odessa Vodka 20cl"
>   ,"value":"Odessa Vodka 20cl"},{"full_name":"Marula","value":"Marula"},{"full_name":"Maderia Verdelho
>    15yr old","value":"Maderia Verdelho 15yr old"},{"full_name":"Madeira Malsmey 15yr old","value":"Madeira
>    Malsmey 15yr old"},{"full_name":"Hennessey 5cl","value":"Hennessey 5cl"},{"full_name":"Jack Daniels
>    35cl","value":"Jack Daniels 35cl"},{"full_name":"Madeira Bual 10 yr old","value":"Madeira Bual 10 yr
>    old"}]

However, the way that the results are displayed in the text box is incorrect. What gets displayed is the whole line "value":"Jack Daniels 35cl" for example which each character being a separate entry in the text box.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use item.value in the callback function:

> label: item.value    value: item.value

```
$('#customerAutocomplte').autocomplete({

        source: function( request, response ) {
        var dept = $('#customerAutocomplte').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo Navigation::gUrl('/users/admin/stocktake_details_nonbcodeditems.php', array('stocktake_id' => $stocktake_id, 'action' => 'find_products'));?>',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'dept':dept},
                     success: function( data ) {
                     response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                        return {
                            label: item.value,
                            value: item.value
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        autoFocus: true,
        minLength: 0        
      });
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly that didn't help. Now, I managed to split the lines by using the following:
    success: function(data) {
                    //var lines = data.split("\n");
                    response(data.split(","));
          }});

But now the result comes out as:  ["Smirnoff 20Cl"]. Any ideas why JQuery is not doing what its supposed to?

Comment: Did you try to just define the source parameter ? Put only the url in the source parameter and let the phpscript do the formatting.